# Twitter.framework in Mountain Lion?

Tags: cocoa, twitter, osx-mountain-lion, twrequest

I'm playing with the new stuff in Mountain Lion, and so I booted up a new Mountain Lion Cocoa app - I got the ACAccount Stuff working right away, but when I went to include the Twitter.framework file, it isn't there!

All the apple docs I've seen mention it, I'm running XCode 4.4 & XCode 4.5-2, Neither of which appear to show it as an available framework.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, did some more digging, and it looks like TWRequest-like methods are wrapped inside of SLRequest, part of Social.framework. I'll leave this here for reference.

Comment: See also [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I tried my best to rtfm here, but got lost in some cocoa-ios documentation overlap, and was expecting cocoa docs on TWRequest. d'oh!